# I'm getting a matmul: input operand 1 has a mismatch...error...full error in body

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The error:
`ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 2)`

I'm doing linear regression with a csv dataframe. After reshaping and fitting the x and y values i run into this error, highlighting the model.predict part.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import requests
import io 
import csv

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DairyProducts/misc/main/cadeath.csv"
download = requests.get(url).content

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(download.decode('utf-8')))

x = df['x'].to_numpy()
y = df['y'].to_numpy()

model = LinearRegression()
x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
model.fit(x, y)
r_sq = model.score(x, y)
y_pred = model.intercept_ + np.sum(model.coef_ * x, axis=1)
x_new = np.arange(10).reshape((-1, 2))
y_new = model.predict(x_new)
plt.plot(x_new, y_new)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Look at the `traceback` to identify where the error occurs.  If it is deep in the `predict` call, you need to (some how) trace the problem arrays back to your parameters.  `matmul/@` has specific rules about how dimensions relate.  Evidently your arrays (`x_new` etc) don't conform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The x shape you fit the model in `model.fit(x, y)` is `(361, 1)`. The x shape you `predict` in `model.predict(x_new)` is `(5, 2)`. Their second dimension doesn't match. You may need to change `x_new` shape like

```py
x_new = np.arange(10).reshape((-1, 1))
```